# DevExpress XRPictureBox ImageUrl

Tags: model-view-controller, devexpress

[Sorry for my bad english]

I made a report about a job applicant profiles where the path of the applicant photo stored in the database . 
I tried the following code :

```
private void ApplicantForm_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    objectDataSource1.Fill();
    //   this.xrPictureBox1.ImageUrl = @"\\10.10.101.186\photo\" + Report.GetCurrentColumnValue("APPLICANT_PHOTO");                
}
```

But all the photos that displayed was a picture of the first applicant. 
Is there anything wrong with my code ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put the code in the event BeforePrint of xrPictureBox1 :

```
private void xrPictureBox1_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    xrPictureBox1.ImageUrl = @"\\10.10.101.186\photo\" + Report.GetCurrentColumnValue("APPLICANT_PHOTO");
}
```